# The twelve months not necessarily be observed?

Tags: marriage, talmud-bavli, mishneh-torah

According to various rabbinic sources, after an engagement twelve months (one year) must follow for effective coexistence (Nisuin): Talmud, mKetubot 5,2; 57b; mNedarin 10.5 but also Mishneh Torah, Sefer Nashim, Hilkhot Ishut 10.17 and Shulhan Arukh, Even HaEzer 56.1. The question is, could these twelve months not necessarily be observed? I think so. Indeed according to John Cooper: "Nonetheless, it has been noted that rabbinic discussions stated that girls were betrothed at twelve years, followed by marriage and cohabitation a year later, but this does not seem to have accorded with common practice" (John Cooper, The Child in Jewish History, J. Aronson, Lanham 1996 p. 44). Are there any sources confirming this? In the sense, after an engagement is it possible (if you want to) live together immediately and not wait 12 months? Does Halakhah prohibit it? I think not. In fact, it seems like just advice.

Comment: Consider that common practice today has kiddushin followed almost immediately by nisuin

Comment: Also note that betrothal (kiddushin) is quite different from what people refer to today as ‘engagement’

Comment: If you look at the Gemara there in Kesubos, there is a qualification that there 12 month requirement is only for a girl between 12 and 12.5. Once she’s past that age, there is only a 30 day waiting requirement. Since most girls no longer get engaged at 12 there is no 12 month waiting period either

Comment: (In addition to anything else) the twelve months was so that the girl could prepare the needs of the household (i.e. the assumption is not that you cannot have an effective relationship without a waiting period between betrothal and marriage).

Comment: Yes, but is it mandatory for a 12 year old (also under) girl? I say this, because, the Talmud, precisely in Masekhet Soferim 43b states that "When Rebecca left her father's house she was three years and three days old", which means that one could already live together at this age, therefore less than 12 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have severely misunderstood the sources. They are not saying that everyone **must** wait, they are saying that after the *eirusin* (betrothal) and a תביעה (request that the final part of the marriage take place), the husband or wife can **choose** to be מעכב (delay) the *nisuin* (moving in together) for up to twelve months. If after this time there is still delay by the husband, he must start financially supporting the wife.

Nowadays, there is usually less than half an hour between the *eirusin* and *nisuin*. Therefore the commentary to Shulchan Aruch [Beis Shmuel](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.56.3?lang=he&with=Beit%20Shmuel&lang2=he) says the custom is that these laws do not apply.